# How to write item in list to a row on a csv with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a list called `itemresults` that looks like this:

```
['24500', '17000', '60000', '56300', '24500', '24500', '114950', '32000', '70000', '46948', '133000', '49550', '51600', '35995', '44500', '19300', '34200', '39964', '59900', '27999', '16100', '39000', '78995', '19101', '25000', '30000', '72000', '39900', '30000', '29000', '24900', '22990', '52600', '82600', '64000', '13999', '29500', '46800', '95000', '42900', '32500', '3969', '36000', '32995', '24000', '49999.99', '37500', '34000', '47600', '43500', '28500']
```

I would like to write this to a csv file so that each row, would be an item from the list so essentially looking like this:

```
24500
17000
60000
56300
24500
.....
```

I have tried doing this with different methods, but each time, it just writes the whole list in one cell. I have tried using a nested list like this:

```
outputFile = open('outputFile.csv', 'w', newline='') 
outputWriter = csv.writer(outputFile)
outputWriter.writerow([elements])
```

But that still just writes the whole list to the first cell. I am looking to write each item to a new row. Does anyone know how I could achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This Out..

```
import csv

itemresults = ['24500', '17000', '60000', '56300', '24500', '24500', '114950', '32000', '70000', '46948', '133000', '49550', '51600', '35995', '44500', '19300', '34200', '39964', '59900', '27999', '16100', '39000', '78995', '19101', '25000', '30000', '72000', '39900', '30000', '29000', '24900', '22990', '52600', '82600', '64000', '13999', '29500', '46800', '95000', '42900', '32500', '3969', '36000', '32995', '24000', '49999.99', '37500', '34000', '47600', '43500', '28500']


filename = 'outputFile.csv'
with open(filename, 'w') as csvfile:  
    csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile)
    for x in itemresults:
        csvwriter.writerow([x])
```

Comment: This worked great! How would I write a 2nd list in the 2nd column?

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use the csv.writer here. You can just write the numbers directly and format them using `'\n'.join(itemresults)`:

```
...
outputFile.write('\n'.join(itemresults))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular python file handling to achieve this like so:

```
your_list = ['24500', '17000', '60000', '56300', '24500', '24500', '114950', '32000', '70000', '46948', '133000', '49550', '51600', '35995', '44500', '19300', '34200', '39964', '59900', '27999', '16100', '39000', '78995', '19101', '25000', '30000', '72000', '39900', '30000', '29000', '24900', '22990', '52600', '82600', '64000', '13999', '29500', '46800', '95000', '42900', '32500', '3969', '36000', '32995', '24000', '49999.99', '37500', '34000', '47600', '43500', '28500']

with open("outputFile.csv", "w") as outputFile:
  for item in your_list:
    outputFile.write(f'{item}\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

create a DataFrame from the list and then create the csv

```
# import pandas as pd 
import pandas as pd 
  
# list of strings 
lst = ['Geeks', 'For', 'Geeks', 'is',  
            'portal', 'for', 'Geeks'] 
  
# Calling DataFrame constructor on list 
df = pd.DataFrame(lst) 

df.to_csv("result.csv")
```